# How to create a redirect in the .htaccess file, with 2 exceptions

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I've been trying this for a long time, but I can't seem to get it to work. Pretend my website is `https://example.com`, with the additional pages `https://example.com/abc` and `https://example.com/abc-def-g`.
The plan is for all pages, both those that exist and those that don't, to automatically redirect to the homepage, with the exception of the two pages listed above.

Everything I've tried has failed, either preventing me from accessing the website or just doing nothing at all, so I'm trying to start fresh on a blank slate.

This is the `.htaccess` file at the moment:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN EWWWIO
# END EWWWIO
```

This is the standard file for WordPress. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered doing this in PHP instead? HTAccess only works on Apache servers, and requires a less widespread skillset to answer than PHP

Comment: I haven't, mostly because as I was looking online, basically everyone was saying to use .htaccess, so I was thinking it was the right way to go. I'll give PHP a go though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, *before* the existing WordPress directives:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^(abc|abc-def-g)$ / [R,L]
```

This states that for any URL that is not `/abc` or `/abc-def-g` and which does not map to a physical file or directory (ie. your static resources, images, CSS, JS, etc.) then redirect to the homepage.

The `!` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* negates the regex.

This is a temporary (302) redirect.

You don't need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive.

---

**UPDATE:** If your URLs end in a trailing slash then you should modify the `RewriteRule` *pattern*:

```
RewriteRule !^(abc|abc-def-g)/$ / [R,L]
```

Or, make the trailing slash optional:

```
RewriteRule !^(abc|abc-def-g)/?$ / [R,L]
```

Another way of writing the same thing is (as you mentioned in comments) use `RewriteCond` directives to check the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead of the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. This might be easier to read, however, it is marginally less efficient since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is always processed first. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc-def-g/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ / [R,L]
```

Which is the same as (using alternation):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(abc|abc-def-g)/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ / [R,L]
```

Comment: Trying this, it does redirect back to the homepage, but both pages, abc and abc-def-g also redirect back.

Comment: Actually, I got it to work. I added     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/?$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc-def-g/?$  after the first two lines.

Comment: If that works then it would seem your URLs end in a trailing slash, unlike your example? I've updated my answer. Using the `RewriteCond` directive to check against the `REQUEST_URI` is another way of doing essentially the same thing - except it is marginally less efficient.