# Allow requests to resources outside the wordpress folder

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess

I have wordpress website https://example.com. `/wordpress` is never part of the url.

It runs on a dedicated server that runs Plesk Onyx.

The file structure is

```
|
- httpdocs
  |
  - wordpress
    |
    - .htaccess
    - wordpress stuff
  - test
    - file.php
  - foo
- subdomain.example.com
- bar.example.com
```

On my server the wordpress files are in `httpdocs/wordpress/...` I want to be able to access other files/folders in `httpdocs` e.g. `httpdocs/test/file.php` at https://example.com/test/file.php

`httpdocs` is part of the filesystem and is never in the urls.

I've tried the answers to these questions, [one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278523/how-to-create-a-redirect-in-the-htaccess-file-with-2-exceptions), [two](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247741/rewriting-redirecting-request-outside-wordpress), and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule), and none of them have worked for me

There is no .htaccess file in the root dir or in httpdocs.

The .htaccess file in /httpdocs/wordpress

```
# BEGIN FRedirect_ErrorDocument
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN FRedirect_ErrorDocument" and "END FRedirect_ErrorDocument" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
# END FRedirect_ErrorDocument
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: So, is `/wordpress` not in the visible URL? Please post the contents of the root `/.htaccess` and (I assume) `/wordpress/.htaccess` files. (I assume `httpdocs` is a filesystem directory, above the document root and is not part of the URL-path?)

Comment: none of the files needed have been shared here, you'd need to go one folder up and see if there's a `.htaccess` there or look at the vhost configuration for Apache that Plesk has created. Without any of that information this question is impossible to answer. It's also possible this isn't a WordPress question since you're asking how to modify Apache to allow loading non-WordPress files by modifying configuration files you haven't shared. If that's the case then you won't find an answer or solution in WordPress circles and need to look for general Plesk/Apache help

Comment: Confirming for you though, what you want cannot be done from `wordpress/.htaccess` and the possibility of a `.htaccess` one folder up is also very very low. Apache has been configured by Plesk to look inside a `wordpress` subfolder, which isn't a HTAccess thing but a vhost thing, and VirtualHost configuration isn't done from the folder the site is in, it's a server level thing. You should also share why you want this, what problem are you trying to solve, or goal you're trying to achieve that requires this particular solution of putting files/folders 1 level up?

Comment: @TomJNowell ah okay, thanks. There are no other higher level .htaccess files. I'm happy for you to put that as a proper answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I wouldn't do that as it doesn't actually answer the question, you need to figure out where the server Plesk is managing is putting Apache virtualhost configurations, you may need to get Plesk specific help to figure that out. WordPress PHP knowledge is not useful here. Note that there is a very high chance what you want to do can be done another way without doing what you're asking if you shared specifics, by making this generic it's been turned into a classic X Y problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to create a symlink from your document root (wordpress) directory to the directories in upper levels? You'll need to uncheck the "Restrict the ability to follow symbolic links" checkbox in Plesk Hosting & DNS > Apache & Nginx Settings for that to work.